# If a ReorderableListView is nested inside another Scrollable Widget, it doesn't Reorder Scroll to the top

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, reorderable-list

ReorderableListView is nested inside another Scrollable Widget, it doesn't Reorder Scroll to the top. Any help would be most welcome, thank you!.

Here is issue video link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ct3jhA-JNW1kLX_dW1VPwXvFS-IwW77L/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code :

```
  List<String> _list = ["Apple", "Ball", "Cat", "Dog", "Elephant","Apple1","Apple2","Apple3",];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final signInProvider = Provider.of<SignInController>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 4),
              FlutterLogo(size: 200),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Text("Any Text here"),
                    const SizedBox(height: 40),
                    ReorderableListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      dragStartBehavior : DragStartBehavior.start,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      children: _list.map((item) => ListTile(key: Key("${item}"), title: Text("${item}"), trailing: Icon(Icons.menu),)).toList(),
                      onReorder: (int start, int current) {
                        // dragging from top to bottom
                        if (start < current) {
                          int end = current - 1;
                          String startItem = _list[start];
                          int i = 0;
                          int local = start;
                          do {
                            _list[local] = _list[++local];
                            i++;
                          } while (i < end - start);
                          _list[end] = startItem;
                        }
                        // dragging from bottom to top
                        else if (start > current) {
                          String startItem = _list[start];
                          for (int i = start; i > current; i--) {
                            _list[i] = _list[i - 1];
                          }
                          _list[current] = startItem;
                        }
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Text("Any Text here"),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  List<String> _list = ["Apple", "Ball", "Cat", "Dog", "Elephant","Apple1","Apple2","Apple3",];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final signInProvider = Provider.of<SignInController>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 4),
              FlutterLogo(size: 200),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Text("Any Text here"),
                    const SizedBox(height: 40),
                    ReorderableListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      dragStartBehavior : DragStartBehavior.start,
                      physics: NeverScrollablePhysics(),
                      children: _list.map((item) => ListTile(key: Key("${item}"), title: Text("${item}"), trailing: Icon(Icons.menu),)).toList(),
                      onReorder: (int start, int current) {
                        // dragging from top to bottom
                        if (start < current) {
                          int end = current - 1;
                          String startItem = _list[start];
                          int i = 0;
                          int local = start;
                          do {
                            _list[local] = _list[++local];
                            i++;
                          } while (i < end - start);
                          _list[end] = startItem;
                        }
                        // dragging from bottom to top
                        else if (start > current) {
                          String startItem = _list[start];
                          for (int i = start; i > current; i--) {
                            _list[i] = _list[i - 1];
                          }
                          _list[current] = startItem;
                        }
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Text("Any Text here"),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Not working this.